# Does a USB-to-Ethernet adapter provide a full-duplex internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, laptop, ethernet

I have an ultrabook without an Ethernet port. If I use a USB-to-Ethernet (or USB-C-to-Ethernet) adapter to give this laptop a wired connection, is that internet connection full duplex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the dongle supports full duplex (very likely), it will run full duplex.  I have an Ethernet dongle that came with my laptop and it is full duplex and very fast. I use it when transferring huge files.

Comment: How did you verify that it was full duplex, just curious?

Comment: Half duplex is slow, and Full is fast.  I see both green lights on the Ethernet end of the dongle.

Comment: One last thing, I assume the adapter bypasses the wireless NIC then and interfaces directly with the internal network adapter?

Comment: Proper operation of a Laptop will use either Wireless or Wired but  not both at the same time. When I plug in the dongle and connect it to Ethernet, the wireless turns off and the Wired turns on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all modern Ethernet controllers run in full-duplex mode whenever possible. (You could even say it's a requirement for Gigabit Ethernet.) You will see a full-duplex link reported by your router or switch, if it's capable of showing that information.

Note that USB-Ethernet adapters don't just "convert signal" – the adapter has a complete Ethernet NIC inside. The Ethernet connection is terminated inside the adapter and does not actually go all the way to your USB port; only the data is relayed back and forth.

So the USB port of the adapter may run in half-duplex mode (that's the only mode USB 2.0 supported), but this is completely independent from the adapter's Ethernet capabilities.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the RJ45 from the router to the adapter meets an NIC inside the adapter and that NIC parses the signal to data like the native NIC in the laptop. Is that data then sent to the native NIC and from there it's business as usual or is it bypassed altogether?

Comment: Yes, except there is no such thing as "the native NIC in the laptop". There's one inside the adapter, and that's it.

Comment: The laptop has its own NIC or else it couldn't connect to the internet without the adapter. What I'm asking is does the NIC in the adapter completely replace/bypass the native NIC?

Comment: What I'm saying is that your question is based on faulty premises -- the laptop _does not need_ a NIC to be inside. (Either that, or you define "NIC" differently from anyone else.) All of the hardware necessary to produce and receive Ethernet signals is in your adapter -- not in the laptop -- and the software (i.e. the operating system's understanding of networks) does not rely on a NIC being connected in any specific way.

Answer (score 0):

My USB 2.5Gbps adapter runs at half duplex:

```
$ ethtool enx00242788156c
Settings for enx00242788156c:
    Supported ports: [  ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 2500Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

I am not sure why that is, and whether I can safely change that.

This is on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with 5.15 kernel.